# Getting a template using ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I am trying to make a customfield search that can be inserted anywhere it should load the results in the same page so i thought ajax would be the trick but it's loading the same page again for some reason here is my search template code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#SearchButton").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                ulr:'<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                data: { action : 'inline_search', Sinput: $("#searchinput").val() },
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#SearchResults").html(result);
                }
            });
            $("#SearchResults").css("display","block")
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="flexible-content__content">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="row">
            <?php the_sub_field( 'content' ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="row">
                <input id="searchinput" type="text" value="<?= $search_query; ?>" name="s" id="header-search-input" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search …', 'placeholder' ) ?>" style="border-right: none;">
                <bttuon id="SearchButton" class="gform_button button" value="Search">Search</bttuon>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="SearchResults" style="max-width: 70rem; margin:auto;display:none"></div>
```

and i added this to function.php:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
}

function inline_search()
{
    echo "hello world";
    get_template_part('templates/inline-search');
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_inline_search', 'inline_search');
add_action('wp_ajax_inline_search', 'inline_search');
```

Comment: Are you trying search in wp-admin, since you are using 'admin_enqueue_scripts' hook?

Comment: all i am trying to do is load the inline-search template into my page i saw someone used that action so i thought it was needed as a WP configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP part would be like this.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_register_script('ajax-script', SCRIPT_PATH, array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script');
}

function inline_search()
{
    echo "hello world";
    get_template_part('templates/inline-search');
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_inline_search', 'inline_search');
add_action('wp_ajax_inline_search', 'inline_search');
```

Then in js, you have access to `ajax_object` like `ajax_object.we_value`. Use ajax type POST.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
                data: { action : 'inline_search', Sinput: $("#searchinput").val() },
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#SearchResults").html(result);
                }
            });
```

Comment: what should go in place of SCRIPT_PATH?

Comment: Move your script to separate file and place that path instead of that placeholder.

Comment: i am still getting error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: ajax_object is not defined

Comment: you have typo `url: ajax_object.ajax_url,` not `ulr`.

Comment: i am still getting that error i am sure i am doing somthing wrong but i just can't see what is there anyway i can do this while the script is still in the PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @mokiSRB to point it out but the whole problem was a a typo i feed so stupid.

changing ulr: to url fixed it and it works now.